# How do I get the latest version of a branch

Tags: git

I cloned a remote repo, then did git pull. This works.
Then I switch to our develop branch (not created by me)

```
git checkout somebranch/develop
```

Now I want to pull the latest copy of this branch:

```
$git status
On branch somebranch/develop
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$git pull
```

and get:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
```

What?  I just want it to get the latest version of this branch!

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_git/proj(fetch)
origin  https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_git/proj(push)
```

I also tried this:

```
git pull origin somebranch/develop
```

But this gives:

```
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref somebranch/develop
```

This makes no sense - I can see it there in the https://dev.azure.com/ portal, and all the other devs are using it.

I simply did clone, switched to a branch, now I want to get the latest version of that branch. I have done no other commands.

Also, when I just did "git pull", it downloaded a load of changes.

If I do "git branch -a" I see :

```
remotes/origin/somebranch/develop


$ git branch -vv
```

gives:

```
somebranch/develop 7b2abd41b [origin/somebranch/develop: behind 92] V1/V2 SitePageData merge
```

The question is, how to I pull the latest version of this branch?  What is the command or set of commands to get the latest version of a branch which is not master from the azure git repo which has changes from other devs?  Or does one ALWAYS have to manually to the upstream tracking thing to ever get the latest version of a branch, in which case why does git checkout not do this for you?

Comment: How was `somebranch/develop` created? The message you gave usually happens when it's a purely locally created branch.

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -a`

Comment: @matt Branches with a slash in the name ar very common when you use git-flow

Comment: And they are automatically grouped in Azure DevOps, plus you can set security on these "branch folders".

Comment: "git branch -a" lists out pages of branches (hundreds).  all are in the form: remotes/origin/xxx/yyy

Answer (score 1):

You need to set upstream tracking:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/somebranch/develop somebranch/develop
```

Comment: Hi, if this is the case, do you know why it is not setup by default? I have not had to do this in the past for any branches to pull the latest versoins.

Comment: the upstream origin seems to be correct, but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your branch doesn't have "remote counterpart" - a branch that should usually (by default) look like `origin/somebranch/develop`

You might want to check this assumption first:

```
git branch -vv | grep somebranch/develop
```

If it has a remote branch "linked" to it (upstream branch in terms of git), you should see something like

```
somebranch/develop   <sha1> [origin/somebranch/develop] <last commit message>
```

Otherwise it looks like:

```
somebranch/develop   <sha1> <last commit message>
```

In this case you should "link" the upstream tracking.
The question of doing this technically has been already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Optionally you can run before the actual command

```
git fetch --all # just to make sure you have an information about this branch
```

Comment: git branch -vv gives:  somebranch/develop 7b2abd41b [origin/somebranch/develop: behind 92] V1/V2 SitePageData merge. I just cant find a way to get this latest version